# Javax @Size constraint not applied on json request body

Tags: java, json, spring, rest

For a given rest endpoint that takes a json containing a list of documents as the request body we are trying to limit the amount of documents allowed per request. For this we have tried using the javax annotation @Size as follows:

Spring version 5.3.27
Java version 11.0.19

The header for the rest endpoint:

```
@Validated
@Controller
public class DocumentListController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/documents", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    public @ResponseBody RestDocumentList create(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid RestDocumentList restDocumentList) { ... }
}
```

The RestDocumentList class looks like the following:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class RestDocumentList implements RestInterface {
    private long id;

    @Size(max = 25, message = "A maximum of 25 documents are allowed per request.")
    private List<RestDocumentWrapper> restDocumentWrappers = new ArrayList<>();

    //getter and setters omitted
}
```

The json looks like this:

```
{
    "id": 446606713,
    "restDocumentWrappers": [
        {
            "restDocument": {
                "documentId": 1234,
                "title": "Document.pdf",
                "contentSize": 1
                "contentType": "application/pdf"
            },
            "restDocumentContent": {
                "content": "...",
                "contentType": "application/pdf"
            }
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

If i run a unittest on the RestDocumentList class as follows it produces the expected result:

```
@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class TestValidation {
    private Validator validator;

    @Before
    public void init() {
        try (ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.byDefaultProvider().configure().messageInterpolator(new ParameterMessageInterpolator()).buildValidatorFactory()) {
            this.validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
        }
    }

    @Test
    public void testInvalidRestDocumentList() {
        RestDocumentList restDocumentList = getInvalidDocumentList(); //Produces 30 documents
        Set<ConstraintViolation<RestDocumentList>> violations = validator.validate(restDocumentList);
        Assert.assertFalse(violations.isEmpty());
        Assert.assertEquals("A maximum of 25 documents are allowed per request.", violations.stream().findFirst().get().getMessage());
    }
}
```

pom.xml:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
                <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.1.Final</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

When i hit the rest endpoint with Postman or a curl with a json containing more than 25 documents it will create all the documents in the system as if there were no limit.

If i add BindingResult to the rest endpoint no errors are reported:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/documents", method=RequestMethod.POST, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json; charset=UTF-8")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody RestDocumentList create(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody @Valid RestDocumentList restDocumentList, BindingResult bindingResult) { 
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        throw new BadRequestException();
    } 
}
```

So my question would be, what am i missing? What do i need to add for the @Size constraint to result in a rejected request when exceeding the limit?

Comment: Remove `@Validated` from the controller, if it still persists, make sure you have the proper dependencies with the proper scope. Please add your pom.xml/build.gradle so we can see the dependencies.

Comment: Removing @Validated didn't change behavior, i have added the javax dependency. If you could be more specific i can add others as well, but i'm not at liberty to show the whole file.

Comment: THat is depedencyManagement not the dependencies section.